# Play Audio clip x amount into the clip

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine

I'm looking to set the time into an audio clip at which we start playing.

So I can use a 'time progress bar' to set the point into the audio we play from.

Like in a media player where you can skip ahead on a track.

Is there functionality with the unity audio classes that can accomplish this or is there a way it can be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSource-time.html

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/AudioSource-timeSamples.html